# How to unset rest of element except then one index in array

Tags: php, arrays

Have an array i want to unset rest of element except then one index in array

Array

```
$array = Array ( "Result" => Array ( "ResponseStatus" => 1, "Hotels" => Array ( Array ( "Rating" => 1, "Description" => "Description1" ), Array ( "Rating" => 2, "Description" => "Description2"), Array ( "Rating" => 4, "Description" => "Description3") ) ) );
```

Like i want keep only **$array['Result']['Hotels'][1]** and unset rest of index

Want Output

```
Array
(
    [Result] => Array
        (
            [ResponseStatus] => 1
            [Hotels] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [Rating] => 2
                            [Description] => Description2
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I have tried this

```
$arrayKey = 1;
foreach ($array['Result']['Hotels'] as $key => &$value) {
    if (!$key == $arrayKey) {
        unset($value[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you intend to keep ResponseStatus as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) function creating an array with the desired key (keys). In this case `[1=>null]`;

```
$array['Result']['Hotels'] = array_intersect_key($array['Result']['Hotels'], [1=>null]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply copy the needed element out of the array, and forget the original array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrayKey = 1;
foreach ($array['Result']['Hotels'] as $key => &$value) {

    if ($key != $arrayKey) {
        unset($value[$key]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of just including the code, you should also explain what it does and how it works.